# Inequality problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How might one show that $1\over 2m$$[\sigma_p^2+\mathbb E(p)^2]$ +$m\omega^2\over2$$[\sigma_x^2+\mathbb E(x)^2]$ $\geq \omega \sigma_x\sigma_p$?

The immediate thing I think would help is $(\sigma_p-\sigma_x)^2\geq0 \implies\sigma_p^2+\sigma_x^2\geq 2\sigma_p\sigma_x$. But then...?

*Added*: $m,\omega$ are positive constants. $\sigma_x,\sigma_p$ are standard deviations of $x,p$ respectively.

Thanks.

Comment: What are $m$ and $\omega$?

Comment: Symbols defined. :)

Comment: @H.V. I think the connection to standard deviation is not that relevant as far as this question is concerned. So I removed the [standard-deviation] tag and added the [algebra-precalculus] tag. Hope that's ok.

Comment: @Srivatsan: Sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>I assume this is taken from physics textbook or so. In particular, I assume $m$ (for mass),  $\omega$ (angular frequency?), as well as $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_p$ (standard deviation terms) to be positive.</del> *The symbols are now defined.*

<del>Then the</del> The given inequality follows by applying the AM-GM inequality to the nonnegative quantities $\frac{\sigma_p^2}{m}$ and $m \omega^2 \sigma_x^2$:
$$
\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\sigma_p^2}{m} + m \omega^2 \sigma_x^2 \right) \geq \sqrt{\frac{\sigma_p^2}{m} \times m \omega^2 \sigma_x^2} = \omega \sigma_p \sigma_x.
$$

Alternatively, you can also deduce this by expanding:
$$
\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\sigma_p}{\sqrt{m}} - \sqrt{m} \cdot \omega \sigma_x \right)^2 \geq 0.
$$

The two other terms involving $\mathrm{E}(x)^2$ and $\mathrm{E}(p)^2$ are nonnegative, so they do can be safely added to left hand side of the inequality.

Comment: You are very right, this indeed has a Physics context. :) Thanks for the enlightenment.